# How to hide bookmarks from the new tab page in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I don't have the show bookmarks option turned on but whenever I open a new tab, it lists some of the bookmarks at the top of the new tab page by default. Is there a way to get rid of this?

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using? As of [version 15](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/xvkZCMUhfgI), they have [removed the hard-coded bookmark bar from the new tab page](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/chrome/Q308GQTdomM) and made it so that only the floating bar (`Ctrl+Shift+B`) shows if you have enabled it.

Comment: Mine says 20.0.1132.47 m. How do you enable it? I didn't enable it unless it's enabled by default.

Comment: Mine shows up like this: http://freeg131.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/google_chrome_new_page_old.png

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This currently isn't supported by Google Chrome as [answered on the Google Product Forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/chrome/urfrnj9DtTI) dated April 25, 2012. Fortunately though, you can use an extension that overrides the new tab page.

I, personally, would recommend the popular Speed Dial family of extensions. Specifically, [Speed Dial 2](http://speeddial2.com/) for Google Chrome. My current setup looks like this.

[image: Speed Dial 2 - Example]

---

**For those wanting to replicate my setup.**

1. Add a new page using the big **+** button. Fill in the details such as the URL
    and name.
2. All the site-specific images are a deviation of the following URL.

   > http://sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/apple-touch-icon.png

   Just replace the name *stackexchange* with the name of the particular site you want to
    use. **Note**, that for Meta sites you have to append *meta* to the main site name. For
    example, the icon for Super User Meta would be.

   > http://sstatic.net/superusermeta/img/apple-touch-icon.png

Comment: Thanks, is this speed dial 2 you are using?

Comment: @JoanVenge Yes.

Comment: This is now possible, but only if you have no bookmarks: https://techdows.com/2019/03/chrome-hide-bookmarks-bar-new-tab-ctrl-shift-b-shortcut.html

Comment: This solved my immediate need. Ended up using [Unsplash Instant](https://instant.unsplash.com/) for asthetics.

Answer (score 13):

The bookmarks listed at the top of a new tab are actually bookmarks that are in the Bookmarks bar folder. To remove them from showing up, go to the Chrome menu and select Bookmarks > Bookmark manager.

Move all items that you don't want showing up in a new tab into another bookmarks folder e.g Other bookmarks

Answer (score 13):

This is now possible (January 2020) via a Registry edit, via Google Chrome's policy editor. This **will** cause a small note in "Settings" that your Google Chrome installation is now managed by an organization, but it's a small price to pay.

Make a System Restore point before continuing.

1. Close Google Chrome.
2. Press WIN+R and enter in `regedit`.
3. Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies`
4. Create a new key under Policies key and set its name as `Google`
5. Create another new key under Google key and set its name as `Chrome`
6. Now select Chrome key and in right-side pane, right-click and select New -> DWORD (32-bit) Value option.
7. Set its name as `BookmarkBarEnabled` and set its value as following:

   1. **Set the value to 0 if you want to permanently remove and hide Bookmarks bar in Chrome including New Tab page.**
   2. *Set the value to 1 if you want to always enable and show Bookmarks bar in Chrome including New Tab page.*

Confirmed working in Chrome 80.0.3987.87 on Windows 10 Pro x64 (18363) 1909. [Source here](https://www.askvg.com/tip-how-to-hide-bookmarks-bar-on-new-tab-page-in-google-chrome/).

Comment: That's great. Any idea how to accomplish this on Linux or Mac OS?

Comment: Workaround for macOS:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/empty-new-tab-page/dpjamkmjmigaoobjbekmfgabipmfilij


You can still open/hide bookmarks on new tab page using Cmd + D hotkey.


There is also handy extension that adds convenient bookmarks menu:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmarks-menu/ffmdedmghpoipeldijkdlcckdpempkdi

Comment: If you need to have background to be in particular color matching your theme, you can use the following extension and adjust color (there is internal color picker for that inside extension): https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moment-1-personal-dashboa/lgecddhfcfhlmllljooldkbbijdcnlpe

Comment: Thank you so much :) ... still working as of Nov 2022

Answer (score 1):

Use an extension to change the new tab. Such extensions can be found by searching for "new tab" in the Chrome Web Store. The one I use is [The New Tab - Customize Your Start Page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/the-new-tab-customize-you/ddjdamcnphfdljlojajeoiogkanilahc). I have my new tab configured to look like [this](http://prntscr.com/v9otb1).

Comment: This answer deserves more love. Especially your choice of theme 

Comment: The link is broken and searching the Chrome Store with that name does not return the correct hit.

Answer (score 0):

I just use an extension called [Clear New Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-new-tab/felphkbfjadmcejnibcmcncimlappdde) and you can just press CTRL + SHIFT + B to hide the bookmark bar on the new tab page.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the extension 'Homey'.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/homey-productive-and-cozy/lllnjdmfnfjifcfpppjmcnanpokikcpl

You install this extension from the Chrome web store and then go to Setting -> --> On startup, then select 'Open the New Tab page with Homey.
(This may have been automatically enabled.)

Answer (score -2):

I found a solution for this:

1. Click on Chrome options icon > Settings > Advanced Sync Settings.
2. Change `Sync Everything` to `Choose what to sync`
3. Uncheck `Bookmarks`, `History` or whatever you don't want to sync.
4. Click on Chrome > Options > Settings > disconnect your Google account.
5. Go to `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` and delete `BookMarks` and `Bookmarks.bak` file.
6. Click on Chrome options icon > Settings > sign in to account
7. Open a new tab and check if you are getting the bookmarks.

Answer (score -3):

Just create another folder if you don't want to see any bookmarks dont save bookmarks in Bookmarks bar or Other bookmarks.

Simply create a new folder. Voila. job done.

It's that simple.