# How do I customize my shortcuts on a new Chrome empty tab?

Tags: google-chrome

There is one particular site I go to a lot that I used to have among the shortcuts on my Google Chrome blank tab. I accidentally clicked the X in the top right on that page one day and that was months ago. I was hoping it would come back due to frequency of use but it never has. It does come up on my work machine, but it is when I am at home that I use it most.

So, how do I add the shortcut to that site back on to the blank Chrome tab?

I have looked thoroughly through the Chrome settings for it and have Googled for it on several occasions with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/446424/how-to-hide-bookmarks-from-the-new-tab-page-in-chrome#446462) (to a *slightly* different question), you can [use an extension to give you a 'different' (more controllable) new tab page](https://www.google.com/search?q=chrome+new+tab+page+extension).

The reason the site *has never come back*, is because when you hit the `X`, you're telling Chrome "I no longer (ever) want to see this site here".  S you don't.

You may also be able to fix this by resetting your Chrome profile, but that probably isn't worth it (loosing all your bookmarks, history, cookies, saved passwords, etc).

Comment: I was hoping for a non-extension way. Resetting the profile isn't so bad.